# How to interpret this drawing (diode circuit)?

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes, kirchhoffs-laws

I need help how to interpret this drawing of a diode circuit.

I don't understand the voltage \$V\$ after the resistor. 
Does it mean that \$V\$ is a voltage source connected to the ground (right picture)?

And is \$I=\frac{3V-V}{10k\Omega}\$ or \$I=\frac{3V}{10k\Omega}\$  ?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: In these drawing "V" is meant to be the voltage at that node. IE if you put a probe from your voltmeter

Comment: 'V' is just a label.

Comment: *V* is designating a *voltage out*. What voltage will you see at the node labeled *V*?